# Assembler loop and variable

Tags: loops, assembly

I have this code

```
.186            
.model small, stdcall
.stack 128

draw_rect PROTO STDCALL :WORD, :WORD, :WORD, :WORD

.data 

x DB 15

...

.code

...

main:

start_loop:

invoke draw_rect, 160, 100, x, 11111111b

dec x

cmp x, 3

jnl start_loop

...
```

This loop is eternal. But, x is decrementing from 15 (I can see this on the monitor), eternally. I suppose, it should become to be equal 3, or less, than 3. JNL - not less. draw_rect doesn't touch x at all. Why this can be happening?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `CMP [x],3`?

Answer (score -1):

When you use a DB (define byte) macro, the ADDRESS is substituted for the macro into the binary.

The code you want is something like:

```
     MOV EAX, x            ; get the address of x
start:
     invoke draw...
     DEC [EAX]             ; decrement the value at the address
     CMP [EAX], 3          ; compare the value at the address
     JNL start
```